# Add Stripe Fee to Total Cost via Radio Button and JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 radio buttons with 3 different amounts associated with them. Would like to give the user the choice to gift the Stripe transaction fee.

When I check each radio button the cost is updating, but I cannot seem to get the fee calculation to work correctly. I have it working when a user manually enters an amount as seen in my CodePen link below.

The error I'm seeing in the DevTools Console is:

> the first argument to getMessage should be type "string", was
>   undefined (type "undefined")

I'm thinking if I can get `Pgoal` to equal the value of `var $checked` that should do it... Maybe...

Trying to get it working just like this, but with Radio Buttons: [CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/daugaard47/pen/JwLRvZ?editors=1011)

Here is my current code, along with the [CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/daugaard47/pen/maxrBo) and Snippet.

```js
    //JS
    var $radios = $('input[name="radio"]');
    $radios.change(function() {
      var $checked = $radios.filter(':checked');
      document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = $checked.val();
      // console.log($checked.val());
    });
    
    var Pgoal = document.querySelector('#amount');
    var Ffixed = document.querySelector('#f-fixed');
    var Fpercent = document.querySelector('#f-percent');
    var Pcharge = document.querySelector('#p-charge');
    var checkbox = document.querySelector('#gift-check');
    var totalBox = document.querySelector('.total-box');
    
    var totalDonation = $('.total-box > span');
    
    function f(n) {
      return Number((+n).toFixed(10));
    }
    
    function calcPcharge(goal, fixed, percent) {
      return (goal + fixed) / (1 - percent) - (goal);
    }
    
    function update() {
      console.log('update')
      var charge = calcPcharge(
        f(Pgoal.value),
        f(Ffixed.value),
        f(Fpercent.value / 100)
      );
    
      Pcharge.value = (charge || 0).toFixed(2);
    
    
      totalDonation.text((checkbox.checked ? f(Pgoal.value) + f(charge) : f(Pgoal.value)).toFixed(2));
    }
    
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input'), function() {
      this.addEventListener('input', update);
      this.addEventListener('update', update);
    });
    
    update();
    
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', update);
```

```css
    /* CSS */
    input[type="number"]:disabled {
      background-color: transparent;
      border-style: none;
      text-decoration: underline;
      color: tomato
    }
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="40" />
    <label>$40 Monthly</label>
    
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="120" checked/>
    <label>$120 Quarterly</label>
    
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="480" />
    <label>$480 Annually</label>
    
    <h4>Cost $<span id="amount">120</span></h4>
    
    <input type="hidden" id="f-fixed" type="number" value="0.30">
    <input type="hidden" id="f-percent" type="number" value="2.9">
    
    
    <p>Gift fee $<input size='5' id="p-charge" type="number" disabled></p>
      
      <input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="yes" id="gift-check" /> Check box for yes
    
    
    <h3 class="total-box">
      Your total cost is $<span></span>
    </h3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem was that `Pgoal` was using the (non-existent) `value` of the `#amount` span. This should have been `innerText`. There was also a timing issue between updating the `#amount` span and running the update, so I changed `Pgoal.value` to `$('input[name="radio"]:checked').val()`:

```js
    //JS
    var $radios = $('input[name="radio"]');
    $radios.change(function() {
      var $checked = $radios.filter(':checked');
      document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = $checked.val();
      // console.log($checked.val());
    });
    
    var Pgoal = document.querySelector('#amount');
    var Ffixed = document.querySelector('#f-fixed');
    var Fpercent = document.querySelector('#f-percent');
    var Pcharge = document.querySelector('#p-charge');
    var checkbox = document.querySelector('#gift-check');
    var totalBox = document.querySelector('.total-box');
    
    var totalDonation = $('.total-box > span');
    
    function f(n) {
      return Number((+n).toFixed(10));
    }
    
    function calcPcharge(goal, fixed, percent) {
      return (goal + fixed) / (1 - percent) - (goal);
    }
    
    function update() {
      var goal = $('input[name="radio"]:checked').val();
      var charge = calcPcharge(
        f(goal),
        f(Ffixed.value),
        f(Fpercent.value / 100)
      );
    
      Pcharge.value = (charge || 0).toFixed(2);
    
    
      totalDonation.text((checkbox.checked ? f(goal) + f(charge) : f(goal)).toFixed(2));
    }
    
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input'), function() {
      this.addEventListener('input', update);
      this.addEventListener('update', update);
    });
    
    update();
    
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', update);
```

```css
    /* CSS */
    input[type="number"]:disabled {
      background-color: transparent;
      border-style: none;
      text-decoration: underline;
      color: tomato
    }
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="40" />
    <label>$40 Monthly</label>
    
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="120" checked/>
    <label>$120 Quarterly</label>
    
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="480" />
    <label>$480 Annually</label>
    
    <h4>Cost $<span id="amount">120</span></h4>
    
    <input type="hidden" id="f-fixed" type="number" value="0.30">
    <input type="hidden" id="f-percent" type="number" value="2.9">
    
    
    <p>Gift fee $<input size='5' id="p-charge" type="number" disabled></p>
      
      <input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="yes" id="gift-check" /> Check box for yes
    
    
    <h3 class="total-box">
      Your total cost is $<span></span>
    </h3>
```

Comment: Wow. You're good. I've been at this all day. Appreciate the help!